# Confirmatory Factor analysis failed to converge

Tags: python, statistics, factor-analysis

i have  4 item in my dataset and want to conduct confirmatory factor analysis, i have tried following code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import bartlett
from factor_analyzer import calculate_bartlett_sphericity
from factor_analyzer.factor_analyzer import  calculate_kmo
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
def composite_reliability(factor_loadings):
    error =1 -factor_loadings **2  #calculare error for item i
    sum_of_squares =(np.sum(factor_loadings))**2
    composite =sum_of_squares /(sum_of_squares  + np.sum(error))
    print(" composite_reliability = %.4f"%(composite))
def AVE(factor_loadings):
    error =1 -factor_loadings**2
    sum_of_squares =np.sum(factor_loadings**2)
    ave =sum_of_squares /(sum_of_squares +np.sum(error))
    print("Average Variance Extracted =%.2f"%(ave))
from factor_analyzer import (ConfirmatoryFactorAnalyzer, ModelSpecificationParser)
data = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
print(data.isnull().any())
model_dict = {"F1": ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3","item 4"]}
model_spec = ModelSpecificationParser.parse_model_specification_from_dict(data, model_dict)
cfa = ConfirmatoryFactorAnalyzer(model_spec, disp=False)
cfa.fit(data.values)
score =cfa.transform(data.values)
score_dataframe =pd.DataFrame(score,columns=["product positioning"])
score_dataframe.to_excel("latentvariable.xlsx")
loadings =cfa.loadings_
print(loadings)
composite_reliability(loadings)
AVE(loadings)
```

but when i have run this code , i got following warning(there is no any missing data)

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Machine_learning\venv\lib\site-packages\factor_analyzer\confirmatory_factor_analyzer.py:732: UserWarning: The optimization routine failed to converge: b'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH'
  warnings.warn('The optimization routine failed '
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
 composite_reliability = 1.0000
Average Variance Extracted =1.00
```

what does it means?please how to  fix this issue?

Comment: I find that in R is easier to work for CFA. As in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psychTools/vignettes/factor.pdf

Comment: What is going above?, you want to confirmed just one domain?

Comment: that why i switched to EFA

Comment: how many rows of data do you have?